# Best method to load bitmaps in a multi-activity app

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap

I am developing my first android game, it includes a considerable amount of bitmaps. Everything was totally fine until I decided to add a "main activity" to my app that sits behind the game activity.

Before:

```
[Game Activity] --> SurfaceView --> init (loading bitmaps) --> starting the game
```

Now:

```
[Main Activity] --> (user needs to click on "PLAY" button) -->...
[Game Activity] --> SurfaceView --> init (loading bitmaps) --> starting the game
```

Here is the problem. Every time the user clicks on PLAY button, a new instance of Game Activity is created and it has to go through the "init" and load the bitmaps all over again...
EDIT: for example, if during the game user presses the back button.

Clearly, this is a poorly design architecture. Would anyone be able to suggest a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a static class to store your bitmaps, call the load() method when your game firsts starts (maybe during a splash screen), this method also ensures you only ever load each bitmap into memory once.

For example:

```
public class Art {

    public static Bitmap enemy;
    public static Bitmap player;

    public static void load () {
        enemy = loadBitmap('enemy.png');
        player = loadBitmap('player.png');
    }

    private static Bitmap loadBitmap(String filename) {
        //create and return bitmap here
    }

}
```

Then when you create a game object you can just call Art.player to get your player image.

And maybe, you shouldn't be using two Activities but just move around layouts when the user hits play.

Comment: Thanks -- but I read it somewhere that it is not recommended to refer to a static bitmap in a View of a secondary activity- because when the activity finishes, the Garbage Collector will not be able to collect the activity as one of its children is referring to a static activity. Though I'm not sure how accurate this statement is...

Comment: They would never be garbage collected because they are static, they'd exist for the entire application lifecycle from the point you load them. You don't want GC happening because that's a big performance hit.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, Mark Persson (creator of Minecraft) uses this method: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/demos/metagun/metagun-desktop/src/com/mojang/metagun/Art.java